# Como crear un documento dentro de un directorio distinto al directorio del programa

Tags: python, archivo

```
from os import system 

def create_txt(name, nikname, pass_ins, gmail, password_gmail):
     system("mkdir " + str(name))
     system("cd " + str(name))

     f = open(str(name) + ".txt", "w")

     name_f = "name: " + str(name) + "\n"
     nikename_f = "nikename: " + str(nikname) + "\n"
     pass_ins_f = "password_gmail: " + str(pass_ins) + "\n"
     gmail_f = "gmail: " + str(gmail) + "\n"
     password_gmail_f =  "password_gmail" + str(password_gmail)

     text = name_f + nikename_f + pass_ins_f + gmail_f + password_gmail_f

     f.write(text)
     f.close()


create_txt("name", "nikname", "pass_ins", "gmail", "password_gmail")
```

Comment: Hola Javiazcau, ¿cuál es el problema exacto que tienes o dónde quieres crear el fichero exactamente con respecto al script? Simplemente pasa a `open` (argumento `name` de `create_txt`) la ruta dónde quieras crear el directorio.

Answer (score 0):

a la hora de abrir o crear el archivo, lo que puedes hacer es escribir

```py
f = open(ruta/donde/ira/el/archivo.txt, "w")
```

de este modo abriras o crearas un archivo en la ruta indicada y con el nombre que desees, en este caso **"archivo.txt**, asi no tienes que agregar el + ".txt"

te dare un ejemplo:

```py
#en mi caso uso ubuntu 20.04 envez de windows 10 pero seria muy similar
archivo = open(/home/khals/Desktop/archivoDeTexto.txt, "w")
#asi yo crearia el archivo de texto en mi escritorio
```